# Galeria de Imagem SWIFT e Storage do Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, app

Boa tarde,
Estou finalizando um *APP* desenvolvido em *Swift 4*, com *Xcode 9* e *Firebase*.
Eu já consigo me logar com Firebase, e enviar e-mail pelo meu App, o que eu preciso fazer, que não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum é como montar uma galeria de imagem, com as imagens que eu gravo no Storage do Firebase, mas isso de forma automática, eu já consigo enviar as imagens para o Storage do Firebase.
Segue o que eu quero fazer, estou a 3 semanas tentando e lendo vários tutoriais mais não consigo.

**Considerando que as imagens já estão no Storage do Firebase:**

1. Listar em uma galeria de imagem, todas as fotos salvas pelo usuário no Storage do Firebase;
2. Essa lista tem que ser miniaturas das imagens, e ao clicar elas ficam no tamanho normal que estão gravadas.

Obs.: Tem essa biblioteca que monta a galeria de imagem, do jeito que eu quero, mas eu não sei utilizar e nem como eu faria para carregar as imagens automaticamente do Fisebase ( biblioteca:https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)
Poderiam me ajudar por favor.

Obrigado

Comment: O Firebase Storage não tem uma forma de mostrar todas as imagens que estão lá armazenadas. O que você terá de fazer é guardar a lista de imagens na sua Database. Assim fica mais fácil de listar elas

Answer (score 0):

Opa, blza!?

O que fiz foi o seguinte: toda vez que fazia o upload de uma imagem, eu gravava no perfil do usuário o caminho que a foto foi salva:

```
    func uploadImage() -> Void {
    let storage = Storage.storage()
    let nomeImagem = self.nome + ".jpg"
    let storageRef = storage.reference().child("App/Usuarios").child(userID).child("ImagemPerfil").child(nomeImagem)
    let metadata = StorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

    if let uploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imagemPerfil.image!, 0.2){
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if error == nil{
                storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        // Handle any errors
                    } else {
                        self.mEleitorModel.urlFotoPerfil = url?.absoluteString
                        self.gravaUsuario()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

gravava o usuário com o caminho da imagem, no seu caso vc pode criar uma lista com as imagens atreladas ao usuario:

para carregar a imagem, ligue da view no seu código e faça o seguinte(esse cod ai deixa ela redonda, caso nao queira remova):

```
    func carregaImagem() -> Void {
    let url = URL(string: mCandidato.urlFotoPerfil!)
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
    imagemPerfil.image = UIImage(data: data!)
    imagemPerfil.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    imagemPerfil.layer.masksToBounds = false
    imagemPerfil.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    imagemPerfil.layer.cornerRadius = imagemPerfil.frame.size.width / 2
    imagemPerfil.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

Para adicionar uma lista de imagens, crie um dicionário de url, e já manda o dicionário pro firebase.
Caso seja uma lista de imagens, basta colocar um `for` antes de carregar elas.